# Pivot/group data from dynamic frame

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Data is present is in following structure:

```
s.No| Item Name | Source1 | Price1 | Source 2| Price 2| ....
1   | coffee    | website1| 3.5    | website2| 3.5    |
2   | Tea       | website3| 4.5    | website1| 4.5    |
3   | Soft Drink| website1| 1.5    | website2| 2.5    |
```

Desired Ouput wanted either using excel or python-pandas

```
ItemName| website1 | website2| website3
coffee  |   3.5    |    3.5  |   na
Tea     |   4.5    |    na   |   4.5
Soft Drink| 1.5    |    2.5  |   na
```

Process of tabulating is taking a lot of manual effort and is hugely error prone.
Could someone please help me write code for either excel VB script or with python--pandas please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
pvt1 = df.pivot(index='Item_Name', columns='Source1', values='Price1').reset_index()
pvt2 = df.pivot(index='Item_Name', columns='Source2', values='Price2').reset_index()

pvt = pd.merge(pvt1, pvt2, on='Item_Name')
```

which gives us:

```
    Item_Name  website1_x  website3  website1_y  website2
0  Soft_Drink         1.5       NaN         NaN       2.5
1         Tea         NaN       4.5         4.5       NaN
2      coffee         3.5       NaN         NaN       3.5
```

Then, this is the code that currently handles website1, but needs to be fixed so it acts on all such columns:

```
pvt['website1'] = pvt['website1_x'].combine_first(pvt['website1_y'])
pvt.drop(['website1_x', 'website1_y'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
    Item_Name  website3  website2  website1
0  Soft_Drink       NaN       2.5       1.5
1         Tea       4.5       NaN       4.5
2      coffee       NaN       3.5       3.5
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it is definitely good to start with, but could you please suggest when the number of columns are much more (approx 15 columns :( , any other alternatives you can suggest apart from Merge)

Comment: I think I'd try to consolidate all the Source and Price columns (Source1, Price1, Source2, Price2, ...) into just two Source, Price columns. That would make the job a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Using `pandas`, `zip` and tuple unpacking:

```
prices = pd.DataFrame(index=df['Item Name'])
for idx, s_no, item, *row in df.itertuples():
    # print(item, row)
    iters = [iter(row)] * 2
    for source, price in zip(*iters):
        # print(source, price)
        prices.loc[item, source] = price
```

> ```
> Item Name website1    website2    website3
> coffee        3.5 3.5 na
> Tea           4.5 na  4.5
> Soft Drink    1.5 2.5 na
> ```

If `s.No` is the index, remove the `idx` from the for-loop